# Searching for string in the array and/or structure C++

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that asks for the first and last name for however many times the user specifies. After that i want to be able to find the person by last name. However, i am having trouble with finding them. Ive tried searching the array and when i do the program ends. Ive looked at the book and a few online solutions but i cant figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is what i have.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void findPerson(string name);

struct people{
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
};

people peopleArray[2];
string findLastName;
int numPeople;

int main(){
  cout << "Number of people: ";
  cin >> numPeople;
  int x;
  for(int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++){
    cout << "Info for person " << ++x << endl;
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> peopleArray[i].firstName;
    cout << "Last name: ";
    cin >> peopleArray[i].lastName;
  }
  cout << "Search last name: ";
  cin >> findLastName;
}

void findPerson(string name){
  for(int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++){
    if(peopleArray[i].lastName == name){
      cout << "Found person " << name << " at index " << i;
    }
  }
}
```

In my head, the loop goes through the indexes of the array to check for any matches. Instead the program just ends. Im sure somebody is seeing something that im not, ive been at this for a long time and im probably just missing something simple.

Comment: You never called your `findPerson()`

Comment: Also you should make sure `numPeople` is less than 2. since you have this: `people peopleArray[2];` which allows 2 total people. `peopleArray[0]` and `peopleArray[1]`.

Comment: Tip: Consider using `std::vector` instead of C-style fixed-length arrays. You ask for an input number, then completely ignore that, your array is stuck at length 2 meaning any answer other than 0, 1, or 2 is going to crash your app. With a vector you can just `push_back` as many as you want, no requirement to know in advance.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks for pointing i never called the function! I knew it was something simple, i need to get my eyes checked! And also for pointing out the possible issue with the ```peopleArray[2]```!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
cout << "Search last name: ";
cin >> findLastName;
findPerson(findLastName);
```